# React Native Alert

Tags: react-native, alert

I want to make an alert from these icons that says the description of the icons. So when you press an icon it shows alert, my question is how you define the alert title and message for each icon, the title would be the icon name and the message would be the description

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKXHX.png)

my codes for the icons look like this

```js
    let status = item[keys['status']];
    panel.push(<View style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0, bottom: 0, padding: normalize(5), alignItems: 'center' }} key={'status'}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>alert()}>
        <Icon name={img.itemStatus[status].name} type={img.itemStatus[status].type} color={img.itemStatus[status].color} size={normalize(38)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass alert title as parameter, 
eg:

```
...

_showAlert(title, message) {
 Alert.alert(
  title,
  message,
  [
    {
      text: cancelText,
      style: "cancel"
    },
    {
      text: okText,
      onPress: () => {
        //Did tap on Ok
      }
    }
  ],
  { cancelable: true }
);
}
...

let status = item[keys['status']];
let title = 'Alert Title' // Define your title here
let message = 'Alert Message' // Define your message here
    panel.push(<View style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0, bottom: 0, padding: normalize(5), alignItems: 'center' }} key={'status'}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this._showAlert(title, message)}>
        <Icon name={img.itemStatus[status].name} type={img.itemStatus[status].type} color={img.itemStatus[status].color} size={normalize(38)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>);
...
```